# AngularJS two watches which influence each other

Tags: angularjs

I have the following watches in my AngularJS 1.3. application:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.reportInstitution', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(oldValue != newValue) {
            userService.getAllUsersOfInstitutionByInstitutionId(vm.reportInstitution.id).then(function successCallback(response) {
                vm.optionsUser = response.data;
                vm.reportUser = vm.optionsUser.length > 0 ? vm.optionsUser[0] : null;
             }, function errorCallback(response) {
                  console.log('error in recordReport.controller.js#watch#reportInstitution');
             });
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch('vm.reportUser', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(oldValue != newValue) {
            userService.getInstitutionsOfUser(vm.reportUser.id).then(function successCallback(response) {
                vm.optionsInstitution = response.data;
                vm.reportInstitution = vm.optionsInstitution.length > 0 ? vm.optionsInstitution[0] : null;
             }, function errorCallback(response) {
                  console.log('error in recordReport.controller.js#watch#reportUser');
             });
        }
    });
```

So, the influence each other, e.g. if vm.reportInstitution changes than vm.reportUser is set and if vm.reportUser changes, than vm.reportInstitution is set -> this produces an infinite loop.

My question now would be if I can prevent this by stopping the propagation similar?

Answer (score 0):

you can stop/start the watch process with `stopwatchreportInstitution()/startwatchreportInstitution()` like this :

```
var stopwatchreportInstitution = null ;
var stopwatchreportUser = null ;

function startwatchreportInstitution(){
    stopwatchreportInstitution = $scope.$watch('vm.reportInstitution', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(oldValue != newValue) {
            userService.getAllUsersOfInstitutionByInstitutionId(vm.reportInstitution.id).then(function successCallback(response) {
                vm.optionsUser = response.data;

                // STOP the other watch 
                if (stopwatchreportUser != null) {
                    stopwatchreportUser();// arrete le watcher
                    stopwatchreportUser = null;
                }

                vm.reportUser = vm.optionsUser.length > 0 ? vm.optionsUser[0] : null;
             }, function errorCallback(response) {
                  console.log('error in recordReport.controller.js#watch#reportInstitution');
             });
        }
    });
}
startwatchreportInstitution() ;

function startwatchreportUser(){
    stopwatchreportUser = $scope.$watch('vm.reportUser', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(oldValue != newValue) {
            userService.getInstitutionsOfUser(vm.reportUser.id).then(function successCallback(response) {
                vm.optionsInstitution = response.data;

                // STOP the other watch 
                if (stopwatchreportInstitution != null) {
                    stopwatchreportInstitution();// arrete le watcher
                    stopwatchreportInstitution = null;
                }

                vm.reportInstitution = vm.optionsInstitution.length > 0 ? vm.optionsInstitution[0] : null;
             }, function errorCallback(response) {
                  console.log('error in recordReport.controller.js#watch#reportUser');
             });
        }
    });
}
startwatchreportUser();
```

EDIT: look in official documentation at "Returns a deregistration function for this listener."  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there any possibility to start the watch afterwards. The current behaviour is that if I change institution than only this watch works with further changes and vv. ? thanks!

Comment: i edited my answer. I don't get what you mean her 'The current behaviour is that if I change institution than only this watch works with further changes and vv. ? ' sorry